# Use phone number outside the app?

Tags: java, android, phone-number

I don't know if it's possible but in my app I got an activity that show a phone number (retrieve from the web). 
Can I send this number to the main phone app of android? For example to call it or save it?

Comment: "For example to call it or save it?" You can do both, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried nothing because I didn't know where to look. But I found answers here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Comment: Ok, this might help: [Call a number on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5230912/1267661) and this too: [Add number to contact](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2206236/1267661)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `tel:...` `Uri`, where the `...` is replaced by your phone number, then use that `Uri` with `ACTION_DIAL` or `ACTION_CALL`. For example:

```
package com.commonsware.android.dialer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class DialerDemo extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

  public void dial(View v) {
    EditText number=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.number);
    String toDial="tel:"+number.getText().toString();

    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(toDial)));
  }
}
```

The code shown above is from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Phone/Dialer).